# Google sheets query returning the first three rows of a column containing a values in an array

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Here's the link to the example data 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ThqAqYnu9tHpm2bsZbfQ-eagPNf2TTqjXe2mDVvVRV8/edit#gid=0 
What I want to do is find the Value of Column D in the "Desired Results" Tab and use it to populate columns E, F, & G based on the first three rows of the corresponding column of the table in the "Original Data" tab. 
Column D in "Desired Results" is manually entered and is added to/ changed often.
I understand I'll probably have to reformat the Original Data but nothing I've come up with has succeeded. The "Original Data" is also updated and changed often. I'm looking for a sort or VLOOKUP equivalent but am open to other methods.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in E1 and copy and apply to the range

```
=INDEX('Original Data'!$A$1:$C$3,COLUMNS($D1:E1)-1,SUMPRODUCT(('Original Data'!$A$4:$C=$D1)*COLUMN('Original Data'!$A$4:$C))-COLUMN('Original Data'!$A$4:$C)+1)
```